# Do any concave slopes or curves exist? Any brand

Tags: slope

Do you know if anyone has ever made any concave slope pieces? Looking for multiple lengths (2/3/4/5/6 stud lengths). Basically the opposite of this style: [image]

I would also be looking for the same concave shapes, which would go underneath, similar to this: [image]

The first example is a graduated curve, the bottom seems to be more of a constant curve. I would prefer graduated if possible, but in the concave direction, with the shallower slope at the bottom, steepening towards the top.
If not, does anyone know anybody that makes custom shapes or pieces?
[image]

Comment: For ready-made pieces, see the answers below. But you can also emulate a concave slope by combining straight slope pieces of different angles.

Comment: Trying to avoid using any straight slopes at all. Wondering if anyone can custom make a piece.

Answer (score 9):

[Part 18653 Brick, Arch 1 x 3 x 2 Inverted](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18653&idColor=63#T=P&C=63)
[image: Part 18653 Brick, Arch 1 x 3 x 2 Inverted]

[Brick, Arch 1 x 5 x 4 Inverted](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30099&idColor=63#T=P&C=63)
[image: Brick, Arch 1 x 5 x 4 Inverted]

And [a few other inverted arches](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=arch%20inverted#T=A)

Comment: 18653 is close, but too tall. Hoping for more of a gradual slope for the edge chines.

Answer (score 5):

There's also these large pieces used in some Sports sets.

[Sports Arena Section / Skateboard Ramp](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43085#T=C):

[image]

[Sports Arena Section / Skateboard Ramp Corner](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43086#T=C)

[image]

Answer (score -2):

For the concave shapes that go underneath, there are a lot of [bridges and archs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=arch%20%20-pattern#T=P&P=3) from LEGO.